# Android AsyncHttpClient post() into infinite loop in Fragment

Tags: java, android, post, android-fragments, asynchttpclient

I'm using the `android-async-http-1.4.4.jar` library, here is what my code looks like, I left out the declaration/implementation of `REMOTE_PHP_URL` and `entityJSON` on purpose (assume they are implemented correctly).

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);

        mFindButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

                //entityJSON and REMOTE_PHP_URL are implemented correctly

                client.post(getActivity(), REMOTE_PHP_URL, entityJSON, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(JSONObject jsonResultObject) {
                        /*Success Code here*/
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it executes `client.post` LogCat displays:

`dalvikvm GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1463K, 21% free 6851K/8628K, paused 4ms, total 4ms`

over and over again (infinite loop) until I stop the process in DDMS. LogCat doesn't display any (red) errors.

Keep in mind, the above code runs in other activities in my app just fine.  I think it may have something to do with the fact that it's running in a Fragment or something to do with the context or both. I'm new to android, should I be using something other than `getActivity()` for the context?

I've tried to update to `android-async-http-1.4.5.jar` but when I do, I can't `@Override` `onSuccess()` for some reason.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, my PHP file was not returning a proper `JSONObject`. I accidentally had left a few `echo`'s in my PHP file for debugging purposes and forgot to remove them.  There was nothing wrong with the `client.post` statement!